# Connecting Linux MIDI source to iOS Network Midi device?

Tags: midi

I'd like to send MIDI data from a Linux box to an app on an iPhone (Animoog) which supports Network MIDI connections.  As I understand it, the Apple Network MIDI spec uses RTP plus Bonjour to establish sessions.

I have found a Linux tool called midistream (from the [Scenic](http://scenic.sat.qc.ca/en/Scenic) project) which purports to stream MIDI over RTP.  However, I can't get midistream and Animoog (or MidiBridge, a MIDI diagnostic/routing app for iPhone) to talk to each other.

Anyone know how to connect a Linux MIDI source to an iPhone app over wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"RTP MIDI" in the iOS world is a combination of two standards:
the RFC 4596/6295 standard for sending MIDI streams over RTP
links, and a thin session management protocol Apple invented
for setting up the RTP MIDI sessions. The Scenic project appears
to support the first but not the second, and thus won't work in
your application. To my knowledge, no one has done a Linux tool
that does what you want. The only idea that comes to mind is to
try and get Tobias Erichsen's Windows rtpMIDI driver to work for
you using one of the common methods for getting a Windows
app to run on a predominantly Linux box (WINE, dual booting, 
a VM with Windows running on one of the virtual machines, etc).

Comment: Thanks... not the answer I had hoped to hear, but it was the one I expected.

Comment: Be aware that by design Wine won't run windows drivers.